# How to resolve this issue in Pywinauto to run .msi installer

Tags: python, windows-installer, pywinauto

If running through pywinauto giving error..

```
from pywinauto.application import *
commands=command+'\msiexec.exe /i "....msi"'
app=Application.Start(commands)
```

error is raise AppStartError(message)
AppStartError: Could not create the process

Comment: MSI installers can typically be automated directly by other means; avoid using GUI control where possible; it's much more fragile.

Comment: What is `command`? (Thus, what is `commands`?)

Comment: command is just a path where msi installer package is placed

Comment: What is it *actually*? It's important. You're trying to execute `command + '\msiexec.exe'`, so the value is rather important. It's the nub of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally `commands` should have the next form

```
r'"C:\Program Files\...\some.exe" /configure'
```

So, I suppose in your case should be something like that

```
commands=r'"%s\msiexec.exe" /i ....msi' % command
```

(be careful with slash before msiexec.exe)

But I agree with @Chris Morgan, maybe pywinauto is not the best way for .msi